# Identifying transistor feedback type

Tags: feedback

How can we identify the type of sampling and mixing in any transistor circuit with feedback ? I have tried to do that but I couldn't. Please help me with the type of feedback in the image I post. If I am right that must be voltage sampling with current feedback [image]

Comment: "Sampling and mixing" is a strange way of describing any transistor circuit. Maybe start your research by looking up "Common Base Transistor Configuration".

Comment: @F.Bloggs I meant only circuits with feedback

Comment: Search for "Dual Feedback Transistor Biasing"

Comment: @KrishnShweta I want method to find feedback type in general to any transistor circuit with feedback

Comment: I think [this](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/transistor-biasing.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: @KrishnShweta Sorry I am looking to identify feedback types like voltage-series, current-series, voltage-shunt and current-shunt